# Creating a two dimentional array in the Play! Framework

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm trying to store a table of data in a two dimensional collection.
Whenever I:

```
@OneToMany
public List<List<Cell>> cells;
```

I get a JPA error:

JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: models.Table.cells[java.util.List]

Cell is a class that I created, it's basically a String decorator.  Any ideas?  I just need a two dimensional matrix that i can store.

```
@Entity public class Table extends Model {

    @OneToMany
    public List<Row> rows;

    public Table() {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        this.save();
    }

}

@Entity public class Row extends Model {

    @OneToMany
    public List<Cell> cells;

    public Row() {
        this.cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        this.save();
    }

}

@Entity public class Cell extends Model {

    public String content;

    public Cell(String content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, `@OneToMany` only works with List of Entities. You are doing a List of a List, which is not an entity, so it fails.

Try to change the model to:

Table > Row > Cell

All of them via @OneToMany, so you can have your 2-dimensional structure but with Entities.

EDIT:

I believe your model declaration is not correct. Try this one:

```
@Entity public class Table extends Model {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="table")
    public List<Row> rows;

    public Table() {
        this.rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
    }

    public Table addRow(Row r) {
        r.table = this;
        r.save();
        this.rows.add(r);      
        return this.save();
    }

}

@Entity public class Row extends Model {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="row")
    public List<Cell> cells;

    @ManyToOne
    public Table table;

    public Row() {
        this.cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    }

    public Row addCell(String content) {
        Cell cell = new Cell(content);
        cell.row = this;
        cell.save();
        this.cells.add(cell);
        return this.save();
    }

}

@Entity public class Cell extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    public Row row;       

    public String content;

    public Cell(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

To create:

```
Row row = new Row();
row.save();
row.addCell("Content");
Table table = new Table();
table.save();
table.addRow(row);
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you said and I'm getting:
JPA error
A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): could not instantiate test objectmodels.Row

Comment: i used your solution, i noticed that you took out the .save()'s in the constructors, but when i look in my database Cell and Row are stored yet Table isn't.

???

Comment: @zmahir I believe it better t process the save outside. Updating code

Comment: using your way, i get the error:

org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Cell.row -> models.Row
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Cell.row -> models.Row